# Returning multiple ID numbers in Excel using an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am working with a set of data in Excel that includes ID numbers and Account numbers. Each ID number contains multiple account numbers. I want to return each Account number associated with each ID number vertically.

I have done research and came up with an array formula that works for the first ID number but does not work for the rest. I have created a sample of my data to share.

```
{=INDEX($E$2:$E$5, SMALL(IF(($H2=$A$2:$C$5), MATCH(ROW($A$2:$C$5), ROW($A$2:$C$5)), ""), ROWS($A$1:A1)))}
```

I am getting a #NUM! error in the rest of the cells. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**`sample data - formula result - desired result`**

[image: sample data - formula result - desired result]

Comment: It'd be much easier to get your desired result using a VBA macro

Comment: I attempted a VBA using an online resource but it yields similar results.

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA, you could construct a Power Query to do this. But you'd need to do either do some advanced PQ programming or use conditional formatting to blank the "extra" ID#'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your provided data setup like so:

[image]

In cell H2 and copied down is this (regular) formula (assumes ID #s are actually numbers as shown in your provided sample data):

```
=IF(ROW(H1)>COUNTA($A$2:$C$5),"",SMALL($A$2:$C$5,ROW(H1)))
```

Then in cell I2 and copied down is this (**array**) formula:

```
=IF(H2="","",INDEX(E:E,SMALL(IF($A$2:$C$5=H2,ROW($A$2:$C$5)),COUNTIF(H$2:H2,H2))))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would the first formula differ if there were letters involved?

Comment: @Jon You couldn't use the `SMALL` function since that only works with numbers.  You'd probably have to use a combination of INDEX/MATCH/COUNTIF and it would be much messier.